# Highlight Text - Native Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a DOM element with text "Hello World". What's the most efficient way to highlight characters "l"?

Comment: Put a `<span>` around them and set its CSS to use whatever highlighting you want.

Comment: Take a stab at it, and if you get stuck, ask a question about the *specific* problem you're having, showing your code and saying what's going wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a `<span>` around them, and use CSS to highlight spans with its class.

```
domElement.innerHTML = domElemnt.innerHTML.replace(/l+/g, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex and the `mark` element to highlight all the 'l' present in word "Hello world"

```js
var element = document.getElementById('hello');
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/(l)/g, '<mark>$1</mark>');
```

```html
<div id="hello">
  Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: It does solves the problem but not very efficiently, as it marks each "l" individually even when they occur consecutively and can be marked in group. <mark><mark/>. We can use another regex to replace the string "<mark></mark>" with null to achieve that but it requires another iteration.